# Use layout_alignBaseline with Spinner

Tags: android, layout

I've noticed that layout_alignBaseline of TextVew control doesn't work with Spinner control.
I'm trying to place a text to the left of spinner, but it goes to the top of the parent control.

```
<Spinner  
android:id="@+id/locations"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_below="@id/userCode"  
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/userCode"  
android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    />

<TextView  
android:id="@+id/locationsLbl"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Region"  
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/locations"  
    />
```

Is it a bug or I do something wrong? The same technique works fine with EditText controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem but found the following workaround

```
<Spinner  
    android:id="@+id/locations"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_below="@id/userCode"  
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/userCode"  
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"/>

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/locationsLbl"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="Region"  
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locations"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/locations"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't align the text using the baseline but as a good enough result for many situations

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Android support base line alignment for Spinners.  The Spinner will create the first View of the list and use its baseline alignment.

If that doesn't work, make sure your spinner adapter creates a View that supports base line alignment. (getBaseline() != -1).  For LinearLayouts, you can use the baselineAlignedChildIndex attribute to specify a child within the linear layout to use.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/locations"` ?

Comment: Can't post images unfortunately. Well it didn't help, but thanks.
To be more clear I have 2 RelativeLayouts inside each other.
    <RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
The fist one is a parent, second one is a child that is placed in the center of a screen. Spinner is paced okay, but TextViev goes to the top of child layout. They are both in the child layout. Solved it using margin.